# Maximum value of $\sin{2x}\tan^2{x}$ between $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I need other approach to solve this question.

**Problem**
The maximum value of $f(x) = \sin{2x}\tan^2{x}$ for $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$

What I have done so far, I find the $f'(x) = 4\sin^2{x} + 2 \tan^2{x}$, and think that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$.
I guess $f(x)$ increases on the interval mentioned. So, it has maximum value when $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

My question is this: '' Is there any solution more simple than my approach?''
Is there a way to simplify the $f(x)$ to get easier step?

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac{2\sin^3 x}{\cos x},f'(x) \implies f(x)=2(2\sin^2 x+\tan^2 x)>0$$
So $f(x)$ is an increasing function and so in $x \in [0,\pi/4]$, we have $$f(x)\le f(\pi/4)=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. You have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(x) & = \sin 2x \tan^2 x \\
& = (2\sin x\cos x)\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^2 \\
& = \frac{2\sin^3 x}{\cos x}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since in $0 \lt x \le \frac{\pi}{4}$, you have that $\sin x$ is a strictly increasing function (and since it's $\gt 0$, you also have $\sin^3 x$ is an increasing function), plus $\cos x$ is a strictly decreasing function. This means the numerator is strictly increasing while the denominator is strictly decreasing, so the overall fraction in \eqref{eq1A} is strictly increasing. As such, this means the maximum of $f(x)$ would be reached at the maximum point in the range, i.e., $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I still don't understand the last two lines,

$\sin^3{x}$ increasing function, $\cos{x}$ decreasing function, this means the max of $f(x)$ would be reached at $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Why?

Comment: @MuhamadAbdulRosid I've added more detail in my answer to explain this. As ($1$) shows, $f(x)$ is a fraction of $2$ positive quantities, since the numerator is strictly increasing and the denominator is strictly decreasing, the overall fraction is strictly increasing, e.g., using some positive integers to perhaps make it easier to see this, you have $\frac{1}{10} \lt \frac{2}{9} \lt \frac{3}{8} \lt \frac{4}{7} \lt \frac{5}{6} \cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin$ and $\tan$ increase and non-negatives  on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$, we obtain: $$2\sin^2x\tan{x}\leq2\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{\pi}{4},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: No real need to use the trig identity $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$. The functions $\sin2x$ and $\tan^2x$ are already increasing and non-negative on $[0,\pi/4]$.

Comment: Yes, of course!